# How to read the documents on apple's developer web site?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am new to cocoa programming, and I was told that the documents on the apple's developer web site are “the best books”, my question is, there are tons of documents, can anyone tell me the reading order for Mac (**NOT iOS**) programming?

Comment: There is no particular reading order. It's not a book nor a series of books. It's by and large references, documentation, guides, and best practices.

Answer (score 2):

Apple's docs are a great reference, not a how-to.

If you're starting from zero, definitely go for some books first.  I'd recommend anything that says "Big Nerd Ranch" on it.  Aaron Hillegass knows more about teaching people Cocoa than probably anyone else on the planet.

- [Objective-C Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321706285)
- [Cocoa Programming for Mac OS X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321774086)

Once you have a foothold on the basics, Apple docs are an amazing reference.  In particular, check out the ["Guides" section](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Guides).  Here are some of the more important ones (in no particular order):

- [The Objective-C Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html)
- [Concepts in Objective-C Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810)
- [Xcode 4 User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215)
- [Your First Mac App](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Mac101/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010611)
- [Mac OS X Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Intro/Intro.html)
- [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html)

Check out the whole guides section, though, there's lots of good stuff there.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask me, I can't say Apple Docs is the best books. They're extremely useful if you want to find smth particular, i.e. you know what you what to find.

If you're new to Cocoa development and want just a kick start it would be better to turn to some kind of 'beginning mac development' book or other development recourses.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Objective-C Programming Language
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html